# No output on the screen word-cloud with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, word-cloud

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = '''python python python python python
big data big dat big data big data big data big data big data big data big data big data
crawling crawling crawling crawling
analysis analysis analysis analysis
visualization visualization visualization visualization
machine learning machine learning machine learning machine learning machine learning
deep learning deep learning deep learning deep learning deep learning deep learning
'''

wc = WordCloud(width=1000, height=600, background_color="white", random_state=0, font_path=r'NanumBarunGothic.otf')
plt.imshow(wc.generate(text))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

image = wc.to_image()
image.show()
```

This is the code that creates the word cloud. Word Cloud is not visible on the screen in pycharm. What should i do. I would really appreciate it if you can tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used your code with the modification using IPython and it works:

```
wc = WordCloud(width=1000, height=600, background_color="white")
plt.imshow(wc.generate(text))

plt.axis("off") 
plt.show()

image = wc.to_image()
image.show()
```

The attached picture is:

[image]